# SQLCMD Version Not Changing/Updating

Tags: windows, powershell, sqlcmd

A windows 2019 server we use to run batch jobs from has been having issues lately. I think I've narrowed it down to sqlcmd being an old version 11. I installed the newest version 15 Microsoft Command Line Utilities, which on my local computer brought me up to version 15. I've verified this by running `sqlcmd -?` in PowerShell. However, when I install the update on the windows server, everything looks like it is all good, it shows installed in control panel, but when I run `sqlcmd -?` it still shows version 11. Any ideas what / if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: What is returned by `$env:PATH` in Windows Server? Is the location where the updated `sqlcmd` is stored listed?

Comment: @mjsqu If im not mistaken, sqlcmd is stored within ```'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\tools\binn``` Which is present. But that brings up another issue, should I have a ```150``` version folder present for version 15? Does that mean there is something else that needs to be updated? I saw that the ODBC drivers need to be updated which is what I also updated along with sqlcmd. That appeared to be the only requirement.

Comment: You could try comparing the folder structures on your local machine and Windows Server to see what's different. You may get more detailed help from people on https://serverfault.com/ which is more to do with server admin

Comment: Look at the log files on server using SQL Server Management Studio.  The log files are in the explorer under Management.  Make sure when you installed new version that you did not create another instance of the server.  Also powershell path may be different than windows path. I would try to start sqlcmd from cmd.exe window and see if you get same version.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a simple fix I found. So simple I contemplated deleting this post. But, running `where sqlcmd.exe` in cmd prompt shows exactly where its being called from. From there, I changed the environment variable path to the new version. This post shows the environment variable path change: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232639/how-do-i-force-windows-to-use-a-specific-version-of-sqlcmd